# Use xml.modify to dynamically create an XML file

Tags: xml.modify

I want to dynamically create an XML file using the `xml.modify` command.
I have a table with a column of type `xml` and I would read that table with a cursor and create an XML file.

I'm trying this code just to make some tests but it doesn't work.

```
declare @root xml
declare @x xml

set @root = '<Shipment></Shipment>'
set @x = '<ShipmentHeader><ShipID>0001</ShipID></ShipmentHeader>'

select @x

set @root.modify('insert {sql:variable("@x")} into (/Shipment)')

select @root
```

I would have

```
<Shipment>
    <ShipmentHeader>
        <ShipID>0001</ShipID>
    </ShipmentHeader>
</Shipment>
```

Answer (score 0):

i fixed by myself after modified a bit the code
the working code is below

```
declare @x xml

set @root = '<Shipment></Shipment>'

set @x = '<ShipmentHeader><ShipID>0001</ShipID></ShipmentHeader>'

select @x

set @root.modify('insert (sql:variable("@x")) into (/Shipment)[1]')

select @root
```

i removed the {} and i have specified the first node for Shipment[1]
in this way i got the result expected